# How to create space between inline-block buttons?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am very new to this, so sorry for any misuse of vocab.
I want to have a space between two buttons, which have an inline-block display. The "margin" property doesn't do what I need it to do.

**CSS:**

```
.pagination{
    background:#155484;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid #155484;
    border-radius:3px;
    position:absolute;
    left:75%;
    top:75%;
}

.pagination li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.pagination a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pagination">
{block:Pagination}
            {block:PreviousPage}
                <a href="{PreviousPage}">&larr;</a>
            {/block:PreviousPage}
            {block:NextPage}
                <a href="{NextPage}">&rarr;</a>
            {/block:NextPage}
        {/block:Pagination}
</div>
```

(This is using Tumblr-specific variables.)

Also if there's anything in here that can be changed or omitted, that would be great to know!

Comment: <a style="margin-left: 10px;" href="{NextPage}">&rarr;</a>

Comment: re:jgetner
Thank you, but this didn't change anything at all. :(

Comment: can we see a code snippet or codepen of the issue?. did you try using padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.pagination{
    position:absolute;
    right:18%;
    top:75%;
}

.pagination li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}

.pagination a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:25px;
}

.back{
    background:#155484;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:3px;
    float:left;
}

.next{
    margin-left:10px;
    background:#155484;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:3px;
    float:right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pagination">
{block:Pagination}
            {block:PreviousPage}
                <div class="back">
                <a href="{PreviousPage}">《</a>
                </div>
            {/block:PreviousPage}
            {block:NextPage}
                <div class="next">
                <a href="{NextPage}">》</a>
                </div>
            {/block:NextPage}
        {/block:Pagination}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are 3 examples that will add spaces in this scenario:

1. **Using `&nbsp;` codes between links**

   link # 1 ( a href ...)

   `&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;`

   link # 2 (a href ...)

**2. Using an empty `<span class="spacing"></span>`**

'spacing' can be defined in css as:

```
.spacing {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

**3. Adjusting the `padding-right` property of `<a>` tag**

```
.pagination a {
    padding-right: 20px;
    // other attributes
}
```

Comment: No.3 is the right way to go, I would actually not recommend the other two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `padding:left` or `padding:right` on the li should work

```
.pagination li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to set **padding:0** on **UL** tag and *anchor tag* define **display:inline-block** and set padding as you want so check below snippet.

```css
.pagination{
  background:#155484;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #155484;
  border-radius:3px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.pagination li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.pagination a{
  color: #fff;
  border-radius:3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background: #155484;
}
.pagination a:hover, .pagination a.current{
  background: #fff;
  color: #155484;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="current">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```